# ngRoute dependency injection error but angular-route.js.min is loaded

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't figure out why the module is failing to load on ngRoute. I have angular and angular-route scripts loading from cdn but I'm still getting the error `Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error`

```html
 <!--Angular-->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.16/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script src="app/index.js"></script>
<script src="app/components/blog/blogControllers.js"></script>
```

```
// index.js
'use strict';

var pdizzApp = angular.module('pdizzApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'blogControllers'
]);

pdizzApp.config(['$routeProvider'], function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/blog', {
            templateUrl: 'blog/view/blog-list.html',
            controller: 'BlogListController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/blog'
        })
});

//blogControllers.js
'use strict';

var blogControllers = angular.module('blogControllers', []);

blogControllers.controller('BlogListController', ['$scope', '$http',
    function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('/api/blog/post').success(function (data) {
            $scope.posts = data._embedded.post;
        });

        $scope.toDate = function(date) {
            return new Date(Date.parse(date));
        }
    }]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `config` block should look as follows, i.e. the method needs to be declared inside the array that you pass to the `config` method:

```
pdizzApp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/blog', {
            templateUrl: 'blog/view/blog-list.html',
            controller: 'BlogListController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/blog'
        });
}]);
```